# CSS - owl carousel forces image to be 100% width

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    items:4,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:2000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true
    });
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .item{
margin: 3px;
}
#owl-demo .item img{
display: block;
height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src='public/media/image/rabobank.webp' alt='' style='height: 122px !important;'/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src='public/media/image/sep.webp' alt='' style='height: 122px !important;'/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src='public/media/image/rotary.webp' alt='' style='height: 122px !important;'/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src='public/media/image/woordbeeld.webp' alt='' style='height: 122px !important;'/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src='public/media/image/kiwanis.webp' alt='' style='height: 60px !important; margin-bottom: 2% !important;'/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src='public/media/image/-.webp' alt='' style='height: 122px !important;'/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src='public/media/image/dj.webp' alt='' style='height: 122px !important;'/></div>
</div>
<script src="<?= $this->getThemeURL(); ?>Assets/Js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

I'll include a picture of how it looks like here ->.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYJoM.png)
Obviously this is not supposed to look like this. How can I set it so it uses the image basic height and width values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try taking the style tag off the images themselves.

Then changing the css style to this:

```
#owl-demo .item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: change to actual photo width;
    height: auto;
}
```

I would also put a max-width on the carousel to stop it growing more than you want.

Comment: This made it way better but still forces the image to be big. I'll put an image here -> https://i.imgur.com/yzIWiGy.png

Comment: @MarkdG, your pictures vary in size, if you want to set the same proportions, then use rule `object-fit: cover`.

Comment: I've updated the answer above, change the max-width to the max-width you want the photo to be.